# Update a site without causing users to logout

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am trying to update my site (core)- i mean for example, `dll` files when I update the site on the server, the users sessions are automatically closed.

How can i preform this action silently?

I believe that `facebook` is an example for that, they update the site in background, without causing the user to logout.

Comment: Add a "Session State Server", either mssql or a server, then set the load balancer & etc up for a blue green deployment. You should check out DevOps!

Comment: Didn't know that, Thanks!